# International keyboard and UITextField secure option

Tags: iphone, passwords, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in a .xib file with the secure option marked as YES.
I have several international keyboards on my device.
When the secure option is set to NO, I have no problem using all of the international keyboards on my device, but when it is set to YES, I am only able to use the English keyboard.

Is there a way to an option I can use to enable this feature, or would I have to do this manually (don't mark the secure option and replace the text the user enters with *'s)?

Thanks,

Comment: Chonch - Did you ever determine how to get international keyboards and secure option YES to work together? If so could you please note your findings here as I am having a similar issue? Thanks! Chris

Comment: Unfortunately not. The only solution I can offer is the one listed in the answer below. It's a bit of a headache, but I couldn't find any other way. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I believe - you need only English characters in your text fields. I prefer you to use following method.
By using this method you can filter out what characters do you need & what is not needed.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

}
```